# How can I double-click on the coordinates of the points with java, iOS device?

Tags: java, ios, appium, multi-touch

I want to double-tap on the coordinates of the points (672, 282).
I tried to use "MultiTouchAction", but no result.
This code is not working for me:

```
    `MultiTouchAction multiTouch = new MultiTouchAction(driver);
    TouchAction action0 = new TouchAction(driver).tap(672, 282);
    TouchAction action1 = new TouchAction(driver).tap(672, 282);
    multiTouch.add(action0).add(action1).perform();`
```

Comment: I could reach upto this - https://groups.google.com/d/msg/appium-discuss/4jhVN4ySSGI/FH9slJqPWioJ ,hope it helps.

Comment: Ths, I tried this method, but tap is hapening only once. What is go wrong? `HashMap<String, Double> tapObject = new HashMap<String, Double>();
         tapObject.put("tapCount", 2.0);     
         tapObject.put("touchCount", 1.0);
         tapObject.put("duration", 0.1);
         tapObject.put("x", 672.0);
         tapObject.put("y", 282.0);
         JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
         js.executeScript("mobile: tap", tapObject);`

Comment: All works good, simply "duration" must be "0": `tapObject.put("duration", 0.0); `. Thanks again.

Comment: i would not suggest you to use coordinates to double tap on it. In case you try to run same test on different devices, your coordinates might get change. Better you use some other locator to tap on it.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with @Gaurav I would also suggest not to use integral coordinates of the screen to perform action unless nothing else works for you. Its better to do the same using elements on the screen and ideally this should work :

```
HashMap<String, Object> tapObject = new HashMap<String, Object>(); tapObject.put("tapCount", 2.0); 
// tapObject.put("touchCount", 1.0); 
tapObject.put("duration", 0.0);
// tapObject.put("x", 672.0);
// tapObject.put("y", 282.0); 
tapObject.put("element", <find your element>.getId()); // the id of the element we want to tap
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; js.executeScript("mobile: tap", tapObject);
```

Comment: yes, ths. But my element hasn't ID or other locators. 
I find an another element, below my,  by xpath and minus some px from him:
`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIASlider[1]"));
         double x = element.getLocation().getX() + element.getSize().getWidth()/2; 
         double y = element.getLocation().getY() + element.getSize().getHeight()/2 - 33;`